# Pull up to refresh Ionic

Tags: html, css, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

How do we pull up close from footer from an ionic app to do refresh or load more.

I'am more interested in the html and css or ionic content component implementing the 'pull up to refresh' view

Comment: PULL UP not PULL DOWN

Comment: Are u using ionic 1 or 2

Comment: iam using ionic 2

Comment: ok and you want func like infinite scrolling

Comment: yes but i dont want it to auto load like infinite scrolling i either need a pull down to load in more comments or a button saying' load more' but a button doesnt look good

Comment: ok please check this link https://www.djamware.com/post/59b0ac0c80aca768e4d2b139/an-example-of-ionic-3-infinite-scroll-or-load-more?utm_campaign=shareaholic&utm_medium=reddit&utm_source=news and load more with ngIf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code helped me in the html side

```
<ion-infinite-scroll (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)">
<ion-infinite-scroll-content loadingSpinner="bubbles" loadingText="Loading more data...">
</ion-infinite-scroll-content>
```